# INSERT INTO select distinct null PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having problem with the following:

```
create table tab1 (col1 double precision, col2 double precision)
Insert into tab1 
select distinct col1, null 
from tab1
```

I can't do that, because of error  column "col2" is of type double precision but expression is of type text

But this has no error:

```
Insert into tab1 
select col1, null 
from tab1
```

Why do I have an error with distinct and no error without it?

Comment: Try adding `::double precision` after the `NULL`.

Comment: did you put `;` after the create table?

Comment: Yes, adding ::double precision is helping here. but my question is WHY error is here? what is the difference between select distinct col1, null  and select col1, null in logic of posgresql

Answer (score 2):

The `DISTINCT` is either calculated as a *hash aggregate* or by sorting, and both operations require that the type of the second column be determined (originally it is `unknown`).

So according to the [rules for determining the type of output columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-select.html), PostgreSQL will resolve the NULL to `text` in this case.

You can easily override that with an explicit type cast.